# Can't replace printed line with \r

Tags: python, string, output

I am trying to print lines, which replace always the one before

```
print "\r Getting hosts %i" % int(100/count*len(lines))
```

This should result in `Gettings hosts 0 - 100 %` in one dynamic line, but it will always print a new line instead.

Comment: What do you think `\r` does?

Comment: Returns the cursor to the beggining

Comment: It's doing that, _precisely_.

Comment: So why doesn't it work then?

Comment: Because a newline is emitted!

Comment: `100/count*len(lines)` will give you always `0`, if `count` is larger than `100`. (Python 2.x) Did you mean `100 * count / len(lines)` ?

Answer (score 2):

`print` implicitly add newline after the string.

To prevent that, in Python 2.x,  add `,` at the end of the print statement.

```
print "\r Getting hosts %i" % int(100/count*len(lines)),
```

In Python 3.x, use following add `end=''` argument:

```
print("\r Getting hosts %i" % int(100/count*len(lines)), end='')
```

Or use `sys.stdout.write` (works both in Python 2.x, Python 3.x):

```
import sys

....

sys.stdout.write("\r Getting hosts %i" % int(100/count*len(lines)))
```

Standard output normally line-buffered. You may need to flush the stream each time you write.

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

---

`100/count*len(lines)` seems strange. Maybe you mean following?

```
100 * count / len(lines)
```

Comment: For completeness; with Python 3’s print function it works like this: `print('\r some text', end='')`

Comment: @poke, Thank you for comment. I added that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

use sys.stdout.flush() to remove the line

```
sys.stdout.write("\r Getting hosts %i" % int(100/count*len(lines))) # or print >> sys.stdout, "\r Getting hosts %i" % int(100/count*len(lines))
sys.stdout.flush()
```

e.g.

```
for i in range(100):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    sys.stdout.write("\r Getting hosts %i" % i)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```